# Automatisch einen deutschen Text von der Du-Form in die Sie-Form umschreiben und umgekehrt

Tags: grammaticality

Ist es prinzipiell möglich einen deutschen Text eindeutig (und 100% zuverlässig) durch einen Computer-Algorithmus von der du-Form in die Sie-Form umschreiben zu lassen und umgekehrt?

Falls ja, wie sieht der Algorithmus im Detail aus? Gibt es Umsetzungsbeispiele von Programmen, die genau das machen?

Comment: Von "du" nach "Sie" umzuschreiben, dürfte relativ simpel sein, wenn man einen passenden Konjugations-versteh-Algorithmus hat. Umgekehrt dürfte wegen der Mehrdeutigkeit zwischen 2. Person Singular und 3. Person Plural ein bißchen schwieriger werden. Da hat auch die "natürliche Intelligenz" ohne Kontext oft Schwierigkeiten (z.B. "Sie haben ihr Auto geparkt" vs. "Sie haben ihre Autos geparkt").

Comment: The answer is 'no'. Language is too ambiguous to fulfil the 100% requirement.

Comment: Schwierig wird es bei Sätzen mit "Er hat ihm das Du angeboten" und falls es ausländische Namen gibt, die Du lauten.

Answer (score 6):

Der "Algorithmus" würde letztlich einfach eine Liste mit Verbformen enthalten

> kannst --> können
>   würdest --> würden
>   gehst --> gehen
>   versuchtest --> versuchten
>   schwömmest --> schwömmen
>   schwömmst --> schwömmen
>   rätst --> raten
>   rietst --> rieten

und diese dann austauschen zusammen mit *du --> Sie*.

Du kannst natürlich auch versuchen, die Liste der Verbformen durch Transformationsregeln abzukürzen (die Beispiele oben zeigen ja, dass da in den meisten Fällen einfach sein wird). Aber das bringt dir dann die nächste Gefahr von Ungenauigkeiten, es sei denn, du algorithmisierst dann auch die Ausnahmen sowie die Ausnahmen von den Ausnahmen.

In beiden Fällen bekommst du nie hundertprozentige Präzision, denn sobald irgendwo ein Homograph vorkommt (ein Wort, das so aussieht wie ein Verb in der 2. Person Singular, aber keines ist), hast du schon einen Fehler.

> Mach die Fliege!

Dieser unfreundliche Aufruf kann einfach genug in die Sie-Form übertragen werden (*Machen Sie die Fliege!*). Eine Maschine jedoch müsste irgendwie davor bewahrt werden, "Mach" als Einheit der Schallgeschwindigkeit zu missdeuten. (Ja, das Beispiel ist jetzt nicht so toll; wer ein besseres hat: willkommen!)

Um Fehler zu vermeiden, müssten Maschinen Texten **verstehen** können, und das können Sie, allen falschen Ankündigungen der AI-Fans, nicht. *Texte verstehen* heißt letztlich, Texte situationsadäquat zu **interpretieren**. Und um einen Text situationsadäquat zu interpretieren, muss man die soziale Situation richtig einschätzen können. Menschen sind darin oft gut. Maschinen... na ja.

Ein weiteres Problem: Das Austauschen sieht nach der obigen Liste zunächst einfach aus (beachte aber das Vorkommen von Alternativformen wie schwömmst & schwömmest). Jedoch fragst du auch nach der Transformation rückwärts, also von *Sie klatschen* --> *Du klatschst*. Hier kommt dir dann die Homographie der Form der 3. Person Plural mit dem Infinitiv in die Quere, und du bräuchtest eine Maschine, die in der Lage ist zu erkennen, wo eine Verbform ein Infinitiv ist und wo eine 3. Person Plural. Da sind wir wieder beim Verstehen bzw. angemessenen Interpretieren.

Außerdem brauchst du Regeln, die sicherstellen, dass du auch Fälle erfasst, wo das "du" fehlt.

> Gib mir mal den Zucker! --> Geben Sie mir mal den Zucker.

---

Nachtrag:

Dem Kommentar von Beta (siehe unten) entnehme ich noch folgenden sehr wichtigen Punkt: Es reicht ja nicht, die Verbformen zu transformieren:

> Setz dir mal deinen Hut auf, du Schlingel! --> Setzen Sie sich mal Ihren Hut auf, Sie Schlingel!

wo auch Personal- und Possesivpronomina umzubasteln sind.

Comment: Beim Imperativ fehlt das *du* grundsätzlich immer. Sonst ist das Personalpronomen für die zweite Person singular immer vorhanden (vorausgesetzt der Satz ist grammatisch korrekt). Der Algorithmus müsste also nach Formen von *du* suchen, wenn es das nicht gibt, den Modus erkennen. Dann ginge es.

Comment: Ein Problem ist auch, dass man nicht alles konvertieren sollte. Sonst würde (Mutter zum Kind) _»Du räumst jetzt dein Zimmer auf!«_ zu _»Sie räumen jetzt Ihr Zimmer auf!«_.

Comment: Weitere Probleme, die hier nicht diskutiert worden sind, sind ja z.B.:1) Zitate in Du-Form. Die muss man unverändert stehen lassen. 2) Was zu tun mit den Fällen, die nicht in Nominativ stehen? 3) Anrede mit impliziten Pronomina müssen erkannt werden. 4) reflexive, possesive und weitere andere Pronomina müssen erkannt werden.

Comment: @Beta   Gute Ergänzungen! Willst du nicht diese Fäll in einer Antwort mit Beispieln versehen?

Comment: @Pollitzer: Dein Kommentar unterstellt ja, dass die Transformation unerwünscht ist. Eine solche Unterstellung bedarf aber selbst des Kontextwissens. Wieso sollte denn überhaupt je von Du auf Sie umgestellt werden? Wenn es bei Kindern falsch ist, dann doch auch bei Freunden/Vertrauten/Geliebten.

Comment: @userunknown: Da stimme ich zu, es gibt Personen, die man per se duzt, da kann man nicht auf _»Sie«_ umstellen. Warum überhaupt umgestellt werden soll, weiß der OP, man könnte sich z. B. vorstellen, dass ein Autor einen Text entwirft, worin eine Gruppe von Menschen per _»Sie«_ oder per _»Du«_ verkehrt und der Autor schließlich meint, es wäre besser, wenn die sich duzen bzw. siezen.

Answer (score 3):

**tldr**: Nein (Jedenfalls bei weitem nicht zu 100% zuverlässig)

---

Die Frage erinnert mich ein wenig an folgenden [xkcd-Webcomic](https://www.xkcd.com/1425/)

[image: xkcd Webcomic 1425]

Die Lösung der Aufgabe erscheint auf den ersten Blick ziemlich einfach: Finde alle Verben und Formen von Sie/Du und ersetze diese. Zugegeben, das wird auch bei vielen Sätzen funktionieren.

Allerdings interessieren einen bei der Programmierung von Lösungen (am Ende) nicht die Standardfälle, sondern die Extremfälle. Nur wenn diese in Betracht gezogen und explizit getestet werden kann man sagen, dass ein Programm funktioniert und genau das tut was es soll. Testen kann man das etwa durch [Unit-Tests](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modultest).

Für mich ist die Frage auch ein Beispiel für das [Moravec'sche Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moravec%27s_paradox). Dieses sagt im Kern aus, dass es vergleichsweise einfach ist einem Computer/Roboter die Lösung extrem schwieriger logischer Aufgaben beizubringen, diese aber komplett Versagen, wenn es darum geht motorische oder kognitive Aufgaben zu lösen, die ein 1-jähriger ausführen kann.

Um aber auf die eigentliche Frage zurückzukommen: Diese fragt explizit, ob so ein Computerprogramm zu 100% zuverlässige Ergebnisse liefern kann. Wie schon in den anderen Antworten geschrieben müsste das Programm nicht nur ein paar Wörter umschreiben, sondern dazu die innere Logik des Textes erkennen und die Sätze korrekt interpretieren. Die Anforderungen an ein solches Programm sind enorm.

Als Testfall für ein solches Programm würde ich übrigens folgenden Satz vorschlagen (passend zur WM)

> Zur Halbzeitpause wandte sich der Fussballtrainer an seinen
>   Starstürmer: "Ich weiß die letzten 45 Minuten liefen nicht gut, doch eines weiß
>   ich genau: Sie schaffen das noch!" Und dann an seine Mannschaft
>   gewandt: Ich bin davon überzeugt: "Sie schaffen das noch!"

Mit einer extrem guten KI könnte das noch korrekt umgewandelt werden. Aber geben wir ihr mal nur den entscheidenden Satz

> Sie schaffen das noch

Außerdem könnte man überlegen, wie mit Eigennamen und Herr/Frau XYZ umgegangen werden soll. Umwandlung in den Vornamen bzw Nachnamen? Und was ist wenn der nicht bekannt ist?

Womit sich die 100% Zuverlässigkeit erledigt haben sollte und ich bin mir sicher, dass uns allen mit ein wenig Nachdenken noch viele weitere Beispiele einfallen würden.

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke schon, dass das geht, aber ob 100% Zuverlässigkeit erreichbar sind?
Ein Miniprogramm schafft das sicher nicht.

Im Prinzip muss die erste Hälfte der Funktion eines kompletten Übersetzungsprogramms für natürliche Sprachen ablaufen, die Analyse des eingegebenen Satzes. Nur bei der Ausgabe wird es einfacher, da die Vokabeln nicht umgesetzt werden müssen, sondern nur Verbformen und Anrede.

Answer (score 0):

Mit [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/de/translator) ins Englische (oder andere Sprache) und zurück ins Deutsche übersetzen und dabei "Formelle Anrede" oder "Informelle Anrede" auswählen.

Comment: Diese Methode mag funktionieren, um die Bedeutung des Textes ins informelle zu überführen, aber das ist weder 100% zuverlässig, noch behält es den exakten Wortlaut bei. (z.B. "Ich *denke*, dass Sie falsch liegen." -> "I think you are wrong." -> "Ich *glaube*, du liegst falsch."). Als ich mtwde's Testfall ausprobiert habe, hat DeepL sogar die Bedeutung verändert und das zweite "Sie" als "they" und nicht als "you" im Plural übersetzt.